Band pass filter with LED
I designed a circuit for lighting up and off an LED according to the pass band frequency range (300-400 Hz). LED light up after 300 Hz and but did not off LED after 400 Hz. What is the problem?


Your circuit is a high-pass filter ... So, when it begins to "amplify" ... it stay on. Note that this may change ... because of internal resistor of generator.

research light organ or color organ

See this https://threeneurons.wordpress.com/miscellaneous-projects/3-channel-color-organ/

Thank you very much for your reply.

You must use a "true" BP filter ... Search with your data parameters. You will find easily.

Perhaps something like this https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/Simple_Bandpass.php


What is the problem?

I see quite a few (NOTE: some of them do not relate to your actual frequency-lighting stuff but the overall circuit design).

C7 does nothing other than load the signal generator.
R12 has no effect. The signal generator has a 0-Ohm output impedance therefore it'll dominate and R12 will bring nothing.
All you have is a C6-R8 HPF (high-pass filter) with a cut-off frequency of ~160 Hz.
Apparently, your idea of using D2 and C4 was to form a half-wave rectifier. But the output is clamped by the B-E diode of the Q2 (the drop across R6 will probably be negligible). This makes D2 unnecessary.
There's no current limiter resistor for D5.


Typically signal generators have 50 ohm output impedance, but to put in perspective, it does not change anything as it is so low anyway in comparison.

Thank you very much for your reply. Can you help me to, on led when 300hz & off when 400hz

@Justme yes, thanks for pointing out but the generator in the simulation (ISIS/Proteus 7 or 8, I think) is ideal as far as I'm aware and therefore has zero output impedance

Here is an example of "what to do" and use.
Made with microcap v12

In color blue are the results of the Transient Analysis for the LED current.
All currents that are above 4 mA will light the LED.
You can see the bandpass of the filter ... between 200 and 450 Hz.
Some adjustments could be made...
